# Pass Message using NSNotification from UITableView row selection to uiViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotification

i'm new in IOS. i look for solution for over a day but all available solution work within a single UIViewConntroller but when i did it between uiTableView row selection and UIViewConntroller as Observer then the Selector is not called  by Observer.

**On row Selection in uitableviewcontroller**

```
 NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Ravi" forKey:@"name"];
NSNotification * notification =[[ NSNotification alloc] initWithName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

**In UIViewController on viewdidload **

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receivedNotification:)
                                             name:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
```

**SelectorAction in uiviewcontroller **

```
    -(void) receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{

    NSLog(@"Notification  Received ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi @Abdul Rehman Warraich, i got your problem. you are posting notification in one view, and trying to observe it an another view. but what happens is, in the second view your observer is not ready (not loaded) to get the notification what you sent.

once you landed in the second view, that time itself observer is loaded.so it obviously will miss the notification.

so whenever you do push and pop, observer will loading as new one. so every time it will fail to observe it.

HINT: Try to load observer in your second view , before you fire the notification. 
Hope it will help you to debug.

Comment: you are right i'm doing it in wrong way. posting notification first and then observing it. BUT have to observe first and then post notification.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich, another way you can achieve your solution. get the instance if the view through storyboard like TestVc *test = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer:@"viewname"] then call view did load before you push [test viewdload]. this is just an idea. will you let you know once I tried

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to creat a NSNotification object. Just post the notification when row selected :

```
  NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Ravi" forKey:@"name"];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

Comment: You don't have to create a notification, and further, the code the OP posted has no effect. This is the right way to send a notification. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

In UITableViewController when you select the row Post Notification:

```
NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Ravi" forKey:@"name"];  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

In UIViewController `viewDidLoad` method addObserver:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receivedNotification:)
                                             name:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
```

Write method in UIViewController:

```
-(void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification  Received ");
}
```

Check if UIViewController's instance is there in the stack? otherwise you will not get the response.

Comment: plz can you elaborate  that  who to check UIViewController's instance  in the stack?

Comment: Please check if your uiviewcontroler is present or it is deallocated. Can you please tell the hierarchy or how you call controllers? ie. If On click of tableviewcell you are presenting controller and there you are observing the notification then it won't work as it is adding oserver after posting notification.

Comment: thank's for the answer it really helpful and work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in any of the above code infect i'm doing it in wrong way. I'm posing notification first and observing after posting notification.
But i have to observe first and post notification after it.

I solve this problem as :

**In AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: load viewControler first so that the observer is ready to get notification(inViewDidLoad) and after that Show/navigate to tableView And then it work perfect.This isn't the proper way but work for me. :)**

***Also Read out the  @karthik and @Priyanka Mistry Answers. Helped me to solve the problem.***

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it would be helpful:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"india",@"Japan",@"pakistan",@"srilanka", nil];
    _mytableView.delegate = self;
    _mytableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:)name:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myData.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *const identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Ravi" forKey:@"name"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:dict];
}


-(void) receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"Notification  Received ");
}

@end
```

in viewcontroller.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{

    NSMutableArray *myData;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableView;

@end
```

Comment: still selector is not called in uiviewcontroller :(

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich i updated my answer please follow the code i hope you will get the result!!

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich are you using two different controllers or you are observing and posting in the same controller? I thought you are using two different controllers as you have mentioned tableviewcontroller and uiviewcontroller in your question.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich add observing NSnotification in UIViewcontroller and posting Notification in UITableviewcontroller thats shit!!!

Comment: yes i'm using two different controls @karthik answer make sense .

Answer (score 0):

Use tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Post notification here
}
```

Comment: i used it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate: but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Stefos' answer is the usual way to post a notification, but if you do want to create a notification object manually, you then need to post it:

```
NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Ravi" forKey:@"name"];
NSNotification * notification =[[ NSNotification alloc] 
  initWithName:@"NOTIFICATION" 
  object:nil userInfo:dict];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: notification];
```

(I don't think I've *ever* done it in 2 steps like this. I always use one of the forms that takes a name, option, and userInfo and creates and posts the notification in one call.)

Comment: It work perfect when i use it in one class but when i try to pass notification between two class then it is not working. (not calling the selector)